# How to construct level order traversal using preorder and inorder traversal.(Without constructing a tree)

Tags: python, algorithm, tree-traversal

inorder = [1,2,3,4,5,7,6,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15]

This is the inorder traversal.

- As trinkot said in the comments- We cannot construct a binary tree using only inorder traversal. Lets assume any random preorder traversal is also given. How do we find the level order traversal without creating a tree.

I want the level order traversal like this.

levelorder = [8,4,12,2,6,10,14,1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15]

I thought of using recursive function like

```
def rec(lis):
    if(len(lis)<1):
        return
    mid = len(lis)//2
    root = lis[math.ceil(mid)]
    array.append(lis[root])
    rec(lis[0:mid])
    rec(lis[mid+1:])
```

But this doesn't work because the second recursive call only happens after all the first recursive calls end.
Is there a way so that I call the first and second recursive calls alternatively?

Or is there another way to find the level order traversal of a tree without constructing a tree?

Comment: If you only have the inorder traversal as input, then you don't really know what the shape of the tree is (there are many different trees with the same inorder sequence). So this is just not possible, or otherwise put: there could be many different answers which all could be correct.

Comment: Oh... okay. Assuming that we have a preorder traversal also given to us then how do we find level order traversal without creating another tree. Is it possible?

Comment: You should edit your question then, and please show your efforts to align with that changed question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, why not?
This isn't the most efficient implementation,  but proper data structure support would take it to the   asymptotic  optimum.

```
def level_order(pre_order):
    path = []
    levels = []
    for x in pre_order:
        while path and any(path[-1] < y < x for y in path):
            del path[-1]
        path.append(x)
        while len(levels) < len(path):
            levels.append([])
        levels[len(path) - 1].append(x)
    return [x for level in levels for x in level]


print(level_order([8, 4, 2, 1, 3, 6, 5, 7, 12, 10, 9, 11, 14, 13, 15]))
```

Comment: Every tree is a BST with the right comparator.

Comment: Sure, but the OP has not given a comparator as input. Just the preorder sequence.

Comment: I would happily take the assumption that the tree is BST. This will solve my problem. Thank you :)